# C++ suduko puzzle, initialising grid - newbie

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am currently extremely new to coding in C++, and I am trying to create a suduko solver. I am at the task now of reading in the unsolved puzzle from a text file, and sorting the numbers into the correct arrays of columns, rows and blocks.

I thought I had managed to do this for the rows and columns (still working on the blocks) however when I have stepped through my code to see if it has been working, the input value always seems to be -1. I think it maybe to do with the fact I use .get() to get the value, however I am clueless on any other way to do it.

I don't believe it is anything to with file itself because I have managed to output the contents of the file before it trys to initialise the grid. Here is my method for initialising the grid:

```
 void SudokuPuzzle::InitialiseGrid()
 {
ifstream sudukoIn("sudoku_puzzle.txt");
while (!sudukoIn.eof()) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 9; ++column)
        {
            bool g = true;
            int value = sudukoIn.get();
            if (value == 0) 
            {
                g = false;
            }
            m_gridRows[row].setCell(column, new Cell(value, g));
            m_gridColumns[column].setCell(row, new Cell(value, g));
        }
      }
     }
   }
```

Another problem I am coming across is initialising the 3x3 blocks. My original idea was to use if statements, as in if row = 1,2 or 3 and column = 1,2 or 3 then make the index 1 etc. However when writing it out it seemed very unefficient and I was wondering if anyone had any better ideas??

Thank you, 
Lucy

Comment: One thing: The "while not eof" pattern is almost always wrong in C++. The eof function will return true only when reading actually has hit the end of the file for the first time, not as soon as there is no more data to read.

Comment: Did you mean `value` always `-1`? have you tried using `sudokuIn >> value` instead?

Comment: @AchmadJP thank you very much that seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void SudokuPuzzle::InitialiseGrid()
 {
ifstream sudukoIn("sudoku_puzzle.txt");
while (!sudukoIn.eof()) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 9; ++column)
        {
            bool g = true;
            int value;
            sudokuIn >> value;
            if (value == 0) 
            {
                g = false;
            }
            m_gridRows[row].setCell(column, new Cell(value, g));
            m_gridColumns[column].setCell(row, new Cell(value, g));
        }
      }
     }
   }
```

Use the stream `>>` instead of `.get()`.